# Cypress after() called only after success

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a cypress test for my web application, being a set of blocks:

```
describe('Test Page X', function () {
    before(function () {
      cy.navigateTo('page-x', 0)
    })
    it ('should work', function(){
      cy.doSomething()
    })
    after(function(){
      cy.navigateBack()
    })
  })
```

The problem is, that after() is called only when it() works, if it() failes because of some error on the page X, after() is not called, and as a result, the test got stuck on the page X, and the following tests for pages Y, Z etc. also fails.

Am I doing something wrong here? How to make after() that is always called?

Comment: Is there an `afterAll`? Would that help?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, because if before() fails, that navigateBack() call would put the app in the wrong state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a technical solution, but there's an architectural solution.

Cypress discourages using after hooks for cleaning states after your tests. That's basically what you do right now.

> if it() failes because of some error on the page X, after() is not called, and as a result, the test got stuck on the page X, and the following tests for pages Y, Z etc. also fails.

That has an easy solution in that you can navigate to pages Y, Z from before hooks, or directly from the tests.

You can check Cypress recommendation on this topic [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks).

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, according to best practices, you should cleanup in before to set the state that you want to start your next test

Comment: To explain the reasoning behind this: As started in [`FIRST`](https://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/oop/naited/Clean%20Code.pdf#page=163&zoom=100,-1,-1) *Tests should not depend on each other*

Comment: Does it mean, that after() is effectively useless, because if it's called only after success, I could place the code called in after() at the end of the it() ?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo: There might be some cases when it comes in handy, but I don't even remember if I ever used it, so the real need for after hook is almost non-existent I think (at least that's my subjective experience).